# How to convert object into string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this value in $scope in Angular

```
$scope.tags = [
            { text: 'test@test.com' },
            { text: 'test1@test.com' },
            { text: 'test2@test.com' },
            { text: 'test3@test.com' }
          ];
```

i want this **result**

**test@test.com,test1@test.com,test2@test.com, test3@test.com**
I am trying to send an multiple email

Do i need to run loop, or  is there is any other way to do this .

Thanks

Comment: send it as a json and decode it in the backend

Comment: A loop seems indeed appropriate for looping something. Did you even  try or do you prefer losing time asking here before trying those few lines of code that would be needed ?

Comment: What you have is a JavaScript object and has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
tags = tags.map(function (el) {
  return el.text;
}).join(',');
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/sedodo/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Or simply `join()` as `,` is a default separator.