# Angular Convert Array into string

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have the following array (testArray) and i wish to extract all the states to string ('Arizona','Alaska','Florida','Hawaii','Gujarat','Goa','Punjab'...). Are there any simpler ways to do that?

```
let testArray: State[];
testArray = this.getStates();

getStates() {
 return [
  new State(1, 1, 'Arizona'),
  new State(2, 1, 'Alaska'),
  new State(3, 1, 'Florida'),
  new State(4, 1, 'Hawaii'),
  new State(5, 2, 'Gujarat'),
  new State(6, 2, 'Goa'),
  new State(7, 2, 'Punjab'),
  new State(8, 3, 'Queensland'),
  new State(9, 3, 'South Australia'),
  new State(10, 3, 'Tasmania'),
  new State(11, 4, 'Penang')
 ];
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26575018/5026957

Comment: It depends on how is defined the class State, and btw it's not related to Angular. Angular is just a framework, that is just a typescript functionality

Comment: @CristianTraìna actually TypeScript is just a dialect of JavaScript, and is not existing in runtime. This is javascript functionality :)

Comment: As mentioned above is related to JavaScript, you can use map function to extract values like
`testArray.map((state) => { return state.name})`

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar or simply `testArray.map( state => state.name )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform .join on value in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607557/perform-join-on-value-in-array-of-objects) and [Javascript turn property of objects in array into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037799) and [How to convert object into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815394)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest way is as follows

```
getStates().map(x=>x.StateName).join(",")
```

Example is given below

```js
function State(id,val,StateName) {
  this.id = id;
  this.val = val;
  this.StateName = StateName;
}

function getStates() {
 return [
  new State(1, 1, 'Arizona'),
  new State(2, 1, 'Alaska'),
  new State(3, 1, 'Florida'),
  new State(4, 1, 'Hawaii'),
  new State(5, 2, 'Gujarat'),
  new State(6, 2, 'Goa'),
  new State(7, 2, 'Punjab'),
  new State(8, 3, 'Queensland'),
  new State(9, 3, 'South Australia'),
  new State(10, 3, 'Tasmania'),
  new State(11, 4, 'Penang')
 ];
}

//Simplest Way is as follows
console.log(getStates().map(x=>x.StateName).join(","))
```

Comment: @scholarwithfire Welcome :)

Answer (score 6):

Well the most simplest way to convert an `array` to comma-separated `string` is

```
var commaSeperatedString = arrayName.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
getStates().reduce((current, value, index) => {
    if(index > 0)
        current += ',';

    return current + value.StateName;
}, '');
```

As a complete snippet:

```js
function State(id,val,StateName) {
  this.id = id;
  this.val = val;
  this.StateName = StateName;
}

function getStates() {
 return [
  new State(1, 1, 'Arizona'),
  new State(2, 1, 'Alaska'),
  new State(3, 1, 'Florida'),
  new State(4, 1, 'Hawaii'),
  new State(5, 2, 'Gujarat'),
  new State(6, 2, 'Goa'),
  new State(7, 2, 'Punjab'),
  new State(8, 3, 'Queensland'),
  new State(9, 3, 'South Australia'),
  new State(10, 3, 'Tasmania'),
  new State(11, 4, 'Penang')
 ];
}

var merged = getStates().reduce((current, value, index) => {
    if(index > 0)
        current += ',';

    return current + value.StateName;
}, '');

console.log(merged);
```